# Why should "current in mailArchive" be a condition for closure?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, conditional-statements

The code is as follows

```
var mailArchive = {0: "Dear nephew, ... (mail number 1)",
                   1: "(mail number 2)",
                   2: "(mail number 3)"};

for (var current = 0; current in mailArchive; current++)
  print("Processing e-mail #", current, ": ", mailArchive[current]);
```

I would think `current < mailArchive.length` would be a better closure condition....

Does `current in mailArchive` accomplish the same thing, as it appears to in [the interpreter](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) (required for print function)?  If not, what does it accomplish and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works in the interpreter, I tested it with a `node.js` interactive session.  `mailArchive.length`, however, will not work as `mailArchive` is an Object, not an Array, so doesn't have a property named `length`.

`current in mailArchive` checks whether the object `mailArchive` has a property with the name given in the variable `current`.

As you may or may not know, however, this approach is not usual for JavaScript.  Much more common is to make `mailArchive` an array instead and use the usual condition `current < mailArchive.length`

Comment: So does it loop until the condition returns false or something?  `current in mailArchive` is true until it reaches the end of the property listing, right?

Comment: Actually, I checked.  current in mailArchive returns false when I just say `if(current in mailArchive == false){print(false);};`

Comment: "current in mailArchive is true until it reaches the end of the property listing, right?" - No, not necessarily.  If for example, the property named `1` is missing in the given object, the loop will terminate early, which is likely not the intention.  Again, the usual use case is to use an array for this.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "`current < mailArchive.length` would be a better closure condition"?
Also, `print` function doesn't really require anything here. It just receives `current` and the value of the `mailArchive[current]` as parameters. It's also not a closure, just as a side note.

Regardless, "Eloquent JavaScript" author only tries to show that instead of using Objects in such an awkward way, there is a build in construct - Array. Which you **will** traverse using `current < mailArchive.length`.

As for what it accomplishes - `in` is an operator that checks whether the property (in this case value of `current`) belongs to the object (`mailArchive` here). Since the properties are named just like indexes ('0', '1', etc.) - it's intent is much like the normal

```
for (var current = 0; current < mailArchive.length; current++)
```

loop.

There are several problems with this, however. `in` operator searches for properties not only on the object itself, but on it's whole prototype chain. Which means that if that `mailArchive` object had a prototype defined for it - `in` operator would have parsed through the properties of the prototype as well. Not something you want in your loops, normally.

There are ways to overcome this. Normally `hasOwnProperty` method (defined on Object) is used to distinguish the properties that belong to the object itself.

The the `for` loop above can be rewritten like so:

```
for (var current in mailArchive)
{
   if( mailArchive.hasOwnProperty(current) )
   {
       print("Processing e-mail #", current, ": ", mailArchive[current]);
   }
}
```

but that is considered somewhat of a bad practice.

Comment: With all due respect--and thanks for answering my question--, it's hard to discern the answer from the argument.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I beg to differ, but that's for you to decide whether you can or can not process an answer as it is presented.

Comment: I thought it was a question you were asking.  My bad.  +1